# Module rest_framework not found on pythonanywhere.com app

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

I am having trouble deploying my app on pythonanywhere.com. I have followed instructions to get teh django rest frameowrk package installed via pip by running the following

`pip install --user djangorestframework`

When I go into my console and run `pip freeze` it outputs `djangorestframework==2.4.3` as one of the installed packages.

However, if I got to my python console and try `import rest_framework` or try to add `rest_framework` as an installed app in my django settings, I get this error.

`ImportError: No module named 'rest_framework'`

How do I get it to be recognized by my console and my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it was a python version issue. It was installing rest_framework under python 2.7 and my application was using python 3.3. To install it for python 3.3 I ran the following.

`pip3.3 install djangorestframework`